# My Access 2007 program can't find the file 'C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Office\Office12\'

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, legacy

I'm on Windows 7 32 bit.  When I open my access program, I get an error message as follows:

> [Program Name] couldn't find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\'.  This files is required for startup.

The above listed directory however, *is* available - I can find it in Explorer, and I don't see why Access wouldn't be able to.

Note that the program I'm running *was* originally built in 2007, so it's old, but it was also built with compatibility with Access 2007 (supposedly).

I'm thinking maybe an Access profile issue, but I don't know where to start really.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked permissions for the folder?  Perhaps your app is running as a non-privileged user.  One thing to try is to run your app as Administrator.

Comment: Your error message is indicating that it is looking for a file, not a folder.  Does it tell you what the filename is that it's looking for?

Comment: And can you open MS Access on your system?

Comment: No, that's the complete error message in the blockquote above. And the error message is from within Access, so yes.

Comment: Perhaps you have a registry entry that should be a file path, but you only have the folder?

Comment: I just edited every registry entry that said `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\` and added `MSACCESS.EXE` at the end.  I rebooted the machine, and started the program as Admin, but got the exact same error. :(